# I want to send sms using at command and php from my win 8 oS

Tags: php, windows, sms, at-command

I want to make an application which will send sms from my 3G modem using **PHP** and `AT command.`
But when i write **AT** in the command prompt it is showing following lines.

```
"The AT command Has been Deprecated"
```

How can i configure at command in windows?

Or is there any other way to do this.

Comment: Use schtasks instead. Find out more by typing schtasks /? in command prompt.

Comment: But how can i send sms using this ?

Comment: AT command is used to schedule tasks. How did you use the AT command to send SMS?

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion here about the `at` command (see SO tag [at-job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/at-job)) which is a command line application to queue a job/command to be run some time in the future and `AT commands` (also called Hayes commands) which is text commands used for communication with modems.

When you write `at` on the command line windows is saying that it no longer supports an `at` command to queue jobs for later execution, and this is also what Mohammad Reza comments on.
This is however not related to what you are asking about.

What you want it some command line tool to send AT commands to a modem. There is one such tool, [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/), which does support this. I have not tested in on windows, but in theory it should work like the following (provided your modem is connected to COM14)

```
C:\> echo AT | atinout - COM14 -
AT
OK
C:\>
```

Comment: Sorry for being late. also Thanks for this solution.